# Logstash http poller- custom header : error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to use an API url to get data from a source.

My api has a custom Header for aw-tenant-code, which works well with a curl.

Here is my sample data:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
    snowsr =>  {
    url =>  "https://url.com/API/system/users/enrolleddevices/search"
    user => "elk"
    password => "********"
    headers => {
        Accept => "application/json"
        aw-tenant-code => "TN37b6rpCi7hJZkdGINQkDukaxccv5bRYOELNm0xB2I="
}
}
}
request_timeout => 60
metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"
schedule => { cron => "* * * * *"}
#codec => "json"
}
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts =>  ["16.75.729:9200"]
    index => "workspace"
}
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Sample data in data source:

```
{
   "EnrolledDeviceInfoList":[
      {
         "DeviceID":24,
         "SerialNumber":"FVJ1WT",
         "AssetNumber":"8D1ACE6812",
         "FriendlyName":"MacBook Air",
         "UserName":"UM2",
         "EnrolledDate":"03/02/2020 16:05:22",
         "RegistrationDate":"01/01/0001 00:00:00",
         "LastSeen":"06/14/2020 07:59:01",
         "Platform":"AppleOsX",
         "OrganizationGroup":"Corp",
         "CustomAttributes":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "DeviceID":104,
         "SerialNumber":"HT3",
         "AssetNumber":"",
         "FriendlyName":"Desktop Windows Desktop",
         "UserName":"UWI",
         "EnrolledDate":"02/11/2020 19:26:58",
         "RegistrationDate":"01/01/0001 00:00:00",
         "LastSeen":"06/16/2020 13:29:24",
         "Platform":"WinRT",
         "OrganizationGroup":"Corp",
         "CustomAttributes":[

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I get an error as below:

```
[2020-06-16T10:51:33,198][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:workspace, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of
#, => at line 10, column 4 (byte 237) after input {\n  http_poller {\n    urls => {\n    snowsr =>  {\n    url =>  \"https://url.com/API/system/users/enrolleddevices/search\"\n    user
=> \"elk\"\n    password => \"*********\"\n    headers => {\n\tAccept => \"application/json\"\n\taw", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:41:in `compile_imperative'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:49:in `compile_graph'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2577:in `map'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:10:in `compile_sources'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:151:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:47:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:24:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:325:in `block in converge_state'"]}
```

What am i missing here? How do i split and get index for each device here.
I am not sure why not one row of got loaded.
Please help me.

Comment: If the index `workplace` wasn't created, then the problem could be in your input request. There isn't any conditional in your output, so you should have an index regardless of if your filter block is working or not. Run your pipeline without any filters and with the output to `stdout` and update your question with the output.

Comment: @leandrojmp, I was able to realize my error after a pipeline issue, however, ive updated the question to the actual error ow, not accepting headers. Pelase help me out.